# How to observe a value change in a sub child node in firebase database in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database in which I store some open discussion forum chat data and now for a add on feature I need o know how many new text messages are there under a specific discussion topic.
Below I am attaching a screen shot to better understand the table structure 
i need to find how many new child added under convo section from it's parent node that is from convo list section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you get the convolist reference in database

```
private lazy var convolistReference: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("convo")
```

Then you need to iterate through all elements in your convolist and count your conversation new childs

```
convolistReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for snap in snapshot.children {
       if let snap = snap as? FIRDataSnapshot {
          if let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
              if let convo = value["convo"] as? [[String: Any]] {  
                  print(convo.count.description) // here you get number of childs for every convo that you might have
              }
          }        
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use like this:**

---

```
var DBref = Database.database().reference()

DBref.root.child("users_1").child("-mdnhrgdyahejkdds").updateChildValues(["blocked": "Change Your Value"])
```